# TypeScript is removing my html import

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I have

```
import MyHtml from "./junkhtml.htm";
```

in a TypeScript file, which compiles since I also have

```
declare module "*.htm" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

in a `.d.ts` file.  When I run gulp-typescript over my project, I get no errors, but the import is completely removed.  It seems TS thinks my import exists only in type-declaration space, and does not represent anything real.  How do I instruct ts that yes, the import needs to stay so Rollup (or webpack) can process it downstream?

---

This is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["./typings/modules", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And this is the gulpfile that I'm using

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gprint = require("gulp-print").default;
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const tsProject = ts.createProject("./tsconfig.json", { noEmitOnError: true });

const dirs = ["applicationRoot", "modules", "util"];

gulp.task("ts", () => {
  var failed = false;
  return gulp
    .src(["./reactStartup.ts", ...dirs.map(f => `./${f}/**/*.ts`), ...dirs.map(f => `./${f}/**/*.tsx`)], { base: "./" })
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .pipe(gprint(filePath => "TypeScript compiled: " + filePath))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(""))
    .on("finish", () => {});
});
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with a new project and just the files you included in the question.  What tsconfig do you use ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - edited - see above

Comment: How do you use `MyHtml` in the file?

Comment: That's it - I wasn't *using* it in variable declaration space.  Post an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript will remove import declarations when they're not used.

If you use the import then it should persist in the file once transpiled:

```
import MyHtml from "./junkhtml.htm";

// use it somehow
console.log(MyHtml);
```

Though not applicable here, in other scenarios someone may want to consider importing only for the side effects as this will also maintain the import after being transpiled:

```
import "./junkhtml.htm";
```